# Godaddy Cpanel .htaccess URL redirect from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule Litespeed>
   SetEnv noabort 1
   </IfModule>
```

This is the code i have,  i tried adding the extra code just below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

.....
.....
.....
failed to redirect to https to http
domain format is: https://*subdomain*.**domain**.com

Answer (score 0):

Have your htaccess file in following way, make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]   
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule Litespeed>
   SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: same issue happening , its still going to cpanel page.
 Future home of something quite cool.
If you're the site owner, log in to launch this site

If you are a visitor, check back soon.

Comment: @RahulPr, moving to http is not recommended though. These rules should work, please do let me know which url you are hitting(as a sample) and what's error you are getting?